# Enabling then disabling experimental OpenGL breaks GUI

Tags: raspbian-buster

After enabling, then disabling, the experimental OpenGL driver, I cannot use the GUI anymore.

1. Autologin to GUI no longer works
2. Manual `startx` and `xinit` no longer work
3. I am getting the error: `Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found(EE)`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing (or reinstalling) the `xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo` package fixes this issue:

`sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo`

or

`sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-fbturbo`